# Trouble proving a tricky inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm working on proving something that basically boils down to proving a particular inequality that I can't seem to make any progress on.  Given $$G(x) = \frac{x(1+x)}{1+x+x^2}$$ I need to show that for all $a\in (0,1)$ and $x > 0$ we have $$G'\left(\frac{1}{ax}\right) + xG'(ax) > G'\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + xG'(x).$$  Graphically this seems to be true, and it basically boils down to showing $$\frac{a^{3}x^{2}\left(2+ax\right)+1+2ax}{\left(1+ax+\left(ax\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} > \frac{x^{2}\left(2+x\right)+1+2x}{\left(1+x+x^{2}\right)^{2}}$$ but I haven't gotten further than that.  I had thought that maybe the racetrack principle would be applicable, but it's not.

Comment: Maybe you can show that the LHS is decreasing in $a$ by computing the derivative...

Comment: Note that the RHS can be simplified to $(x+1)/(x^2+x+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [cross multiply and factorize](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+%28a%5E3x%5E2%282%2Bax%29%2B1%2B2ax%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2+-+%28x%5E2%282%2Bx%29%2B1%2B2x%29%281%2Bax%2B%28ax%29%5E2%29%5E2), you WTS

$$ ( a - 1)^2 x^2 (x^2+x+1)(a^2 x + 2ax + 2a + 1 ) > 0. $$

This is obvious.

Comment: Thank you!  That was much simpler than I'd anticipated.